# Loop through data object array Angular with formgroup

Tags: angular, foreach

I'm trying to prefill some nested formGroup, for this I need to loop through my object array but I got the same error since a few hours...

ERROR : **this.arrayObject.forEach is not a function**

I followed this [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dffny7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) to recreate the same system but I'm not using static data like the example...

I'm getting my list of the objects by my API request and it's inside :

`listTest: Company[];`

[Here is what I get from my API, a list of companies : (there is only one here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QDpu.jpg)

And this is what I tried to loop through my list :

```
this.companyService.getCompanyOfTest(14).subscribe((data) => {
  this.listTest = data;
  this.listTest.forEach((element) => {
    control.push(this._formBuilder.group({
      name: [element.name]
    }));
  })
});
```

I'm expecting to prepopulate my formGroup with every company that I get from my database but I don't succeed my forEach...
Can someone help with this forEach pls

Comment: you need to use `data.companies` for `this.listTest`; `this.listTest = data.companies;`

Comment: companies does not exist for data :/

Comment: your screenshot shows data containing array of companies

Comment: Ok i got what you are trying to do, so i created a viewModelCompany with inside : companies : Company[]  and now I have listTest = viewModelCompany then i can do this.listTest.companies.forEach, but i got 0 companies in my array now and it tell me "Cannot set property 'companies' of undefined"